# grails g:field error not showing

Tags: grails

I have this setup, but the validation is not working

index.gsp:

```
<g:form  name="loginForm" autocomplete="off" controller="company"  action ="save">

<table >

  <tr>

    <td><g:field type="text" name="company" required="true" value="${c?.companyName}" /></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
def index = { 
def c  =new Company()

//c=params
return [c:c]

}
def save ={}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for errors using `hasErrors` method in your form:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: yourBean, field: 'yourField', 'error')} required">
    <label for="yourField">
        <g:message code="yourBean.yourField.label" default="yourField" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="content" required="" value="${yourBean?.yourField}"/>
</div>
```

Grails [hasErrors](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.x/ref/Tags/hasErrors.html) documenttaion.

And check in your controller (save action) if the validation has passed using:

```
    if (!yourBean.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [yourBean: yourBean])
        return
    }
```